# How to import all functions from a python file

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a python file that contains many functions, and now I want to import some of them to another file. I don't think it's wise to do that:
 `from MongoDB import is_circadian_Light, light_devices, occupancy_sensor_IDs, ldr_sensor_devices, lights_with_dimming` because there are many more functions, so is there another solution than `from MongoDB import *` because it is giving a warning that there are some variables that are not used.

Comment: Could you please show us the warnings and the code that causes them?

Comment: `import MongoDB as db` then try to access methods `db.is_circadina_Light() ...`